# how to execute .exe on ubuntu linux/

Tags: ubuntu-14.04

I am new to Ubuntu Linux and can't run an executable file
so far I have tried command:

chmod a+x executable file

then

./executablefile

but error comes

bash: ./filename.exe: Permission denied

need help

Comment: You may be on a filesystem with the noexec flag det (google it, run `mount` to check).

Comment: `.exe` files are Windows files; they won't run on Linux without something like [Wine](http://winehq.org).

Comment: Please note that Stack Overflow is for *programming* questions.  How to run Windows programs in Ubuntu is off-topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A file with an `.exe` extension is most likely a Windows program, which won't run in Ubuntu.  Unix- and Linux-based systems (such as Ubuntu) generally don't use any special extension for executable programs.

The [HTTrack download page](http://www.httrack.com/page/2/en/index.html) has a link to the [Ubuntu package page](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=webhttrack), which shows that this program is packaged as "webhttrack" in Ubuntu.  You should be able to install it via the Ubuntu Software Center or Synaptic, or just do "`sudo apt-get install webhttrack`" in a terminal.

Comment: In this case its good but about other executable files I have how do I run them ?

Comment: You may be able to use [Wine](http://www.winehq.org/) (also packaged in Ubuntu) to run some Windows programs, but you're likely to encounter things that don't work correctly.  Ubuntu isn't meant for running Windows programs; that's what Windows is for.